# Delphi XE threading: how to realize function calling buffer?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, soap, delphi-xe, buffer

I am trying to realize a function calling buffer. My problem is function tied to user's answer. So functions can be executed for long (due to waiting for user to answer) and my functions must be called in this order:

```
  function 1 started
  waiting for user,  (here function 2 is waiting for function 1) 
  function 1 ended

  function 2 started
  waiting for user
  function 2 ended

  ...
```

So function 2 can't be called until function 1 ended.

What i need is something like this:

```
function MyFunc: string;
begin
  Caption.Text := 'Answer required';
  while not ButtonSend_WasPress do 
   Application.ProcessMessages;
  Result := Memo2.Text;
  ButtonSend_WasPress := False;
end;

procedure OnAnswerRequired(Request: string);
begin
  Memo1.Text := Request;
  Memo2.Text := MagicalAddFunctionToCallBufferAndGetFunctionResult(MyFunc);
end;
```

or maybe something like this:

```
procedure OnAnswerRequired(Request: string);
var MyThread:TThread;
begin
  Memo1.Text := Request;

  MyThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure begin
      Memo2.Text := MyFun;
    end
  );
  MagicalAddThreadToBuffer(MyThread);
end;
```

**Update:**

Problem is also that OnAnswerRequired is an event of some complex object and every calling instance is located in its own thread. So I can't just execute functions within one thread.

I am developing testing program. Using this testing program human-tester emulates web-service. The web-service has one function (`function Transmit(text: string): string;`) which is a Delphi web-service function and works within its own thread. When human emulating web-service got text request, he is thinking a lot and then answers. *But* human-tester wants the requests to apear in the order they were created, and the next request must be shown only after previous are answered.

The web-service does not have its own thread. Instead every time when a request arrives, Delphi executes the Transmit function in a *new* thread. Before the function exits, there must be an answer (Delphi will send result inside soap as web-service function's result). And function can't return result value after exited. So i will always have many function's instances. And problem is how to realize FIFO queue for function instances.

Answer (score 5):

Since function 2 can't be called until function 1 ended, there is no point to use threads (things aren't done in parallel). To me it looks like you're unnecessarily complicating things... just call the functions in sequence and show modal dialogs in them to get user input.

Comment: I can't: OnAnswerRequired is an event of object and every calling of it located in it's own thread.

Comment: Please try to explain better what you need to achieve. To me it doesn't make sense to have threads to fire events when you have to respond those events in particular order - essentially youre serializing your threads, thus it doesn't make sense to use them in the first place... Oh, and intefacing with the user (GUI) and mutithreading doesn't mix very well anyway.

Comment: I am developing testing program. Using this testing program human-tester emulates web-service. Web-service has one function (function Transmit(text : string): string;) (Transmit is Delphi web-service function and works withing its own thread) When human emulating web-service got text request, he is thinking a lot and then answers. BUT human-tester wants request to apear in order they were created, and next request must be shown only after previous will be answered. That's it ....

Comment: Use an FIFO queue: when the web service thread receives request it puts it into FIFO and signals "data arrived" event. The main thread (GUI) reads from the FIFO, shows the request to the user and does whats needed. Then it checks the queue for the next item until it's empty and then waits for the "data arrived" event to start proccessing again.

Comment: Web service have not it's one thread, instead every time when request arrives, Delphi executes Transmit function in a NEW thread. Before function exits there must be an answer (Delphi will send result inside soap as web-service function's result). And function can't return result value after exited. So i will always have many function's instances. And problem is how to realize FIFO queue for function instances.

Comment: I haven't done webservices myself so I'm not familiar how they work... I suggest you post a new, better question - ie your previous comment (at 14:16) is much better description of your problem than your original post.